# inputs with square brackets in the name attribute

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, attributes

I searched a lot on this forum to solve this issue I have, but have not succeeded thus far.  I have a form with several `<input>` sections.  In this form I have a password field and a confirmation password field which needs to be validated with the first password.  Here is HTML code example:

```html
<input 
  title="Password should contain at least 6 characters or numbers" type="password"
  pattern=".{6,}"
  name="RegisterForm[password]"
  onchange="this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? this.title : ''); if(this.checkValidity()) form.RegisterForm[password2].pattern = this.value;"
  placeholder="Password..."/>

<input
  title="Please enter the same Password as above"
  type="password"
  pattern=".{6,}"
  name="RegisterForm[password2]"
  onchange="this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? this.title : '');"
  placeholder="Confirm Password . . ."/>
```

Both inputs have a name with square brackets, e.g. `"RegisterForm[password]"`.  If I use name attributes without the brackets the validation works, if I use it with brackets, the validation does not work.  Any ideas how to overcome the square bracket issue in the name attribute without losing the square brackets?

If I would replace the name attributes with `"password1"` and `"password2"`, then everything works as it supposed to do.

If anyone has the solution, please help me out! :-).

Comment: You have an error in your javascript: `form.RegisterForm.[password2].pattern` is invalid. I could help if you'll provide a bit more code, it's not clear where `form` object comes from.

Comment: much appreciate your help. I have provided more code and indeed also noticed the mistake (there was a . between Registerform.[password2], but the issue persist.

Comment: Heh, you pasted a lot of useless HTML, sorry if I was unclear: I'm curious about `form.RegisterForm`: do you build this object yourself? The issue is that `form.RegisterForm.[password2].pattern` will try to access some property of `RegisterForm` object defined by __variable__ `password2`, and I believe in your case this will evaluate to `form.RegisterForm.[undefined]`. BTW, are there any errors in browser console?

Comment: Also what is the reason why you want to keep square brackets in name attribure?

Comment: yes, you are right, bit too much code. i'll adjust a bit in a moment. The reason I use square brackets is because I also use yii framework that provides me with a complete form validation. I was not planning to strip this out, but thinking about it, it might actually better not to use two different ways of validating.

Comment: I have no errors in my error console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I think this is not good practice to put much code inside `on-` event attributes.  As for me, I prefer to define some functions in javascript source file and use them rather than put complex expressions into attributes.

Anyway, the issue is that `form.RegisterForm[password2].pattern` is wrong way to access your input element.
In this case first `form` object is looked up.  Then interpreter tries to look up `RegisterForm` property.  Square brackets is another way to access object's property, but it requires a string.  In your case there goes `password2` **identifier** rather that string literal, and I believe it will try to read the value of variable with same name and look up property in `RegisterForm` depending on result.  So entire expression is invalid and likely will fail early at `RegisterForm` step.

But you still can access your input by name containing square brackets, for example using `querySelector()` function:

```js
var passwordInput = document.querySelector('input[name="RegisterForm[password]"');
var confirmInput = document.querySelector('input[name="RegisterForm[password2]"');
```

Following code snippet works as expected: if entered password is invalid it sets custom validity message to password input, otherwise it sets empty validity message and updates pattern attribute of confirmation input.

```js
function validatePassword() {
    var self = document.querySelector('input[name="RegisterForm[password]"]');
    var conf = document.querySelector('input[name="RegisterForm[password2]"]');
          
    self.setCustomValidity(self.validity.patternMismatch ? self.title : '');
          
    if (self.checkValidity()) {
        conf.setAttribute("pattern", self.value);
    }
}

function validateConfirm () {
    var self = document.querySelector('input[name="RegisterForm[password2]"]');
    self.setCustomValidity(self.validity.patternMismatch ? self.title : ''); 
}
```

```html
<input
     title="Password should contain at least 6 characters or numbers"
     type="password"
     required
     pattern=".{6,}"
     class="input_bx"
     name="RegisterForm[password]"
     oninput="validatePassword();"
     placeholder="Password..."/>

<input
     title="Please enter the same Password as above"
     class="input_bx"
     type="password"
     required pattern=".{6,}"
     name="RegisterForm[password2]"
     oninput="validateConfirm();"
     placeholder="Confirm Password . . ."/>
```

*P.S. structure your code, this will help you in future.*

Comment: Works! Thank you very much, also wrt the structuring. I update my question based on your feedback later today. Again, many thanks!